# Searching for the datasource of tables in a schema

Tags: sql, exasolution

I've been tasked with trying to find the datasources in one of our system schemas. Is there an SQL statement that can do this? I've tried googling and checking the Exasol User Manual but can't find anything.

Comment: The schemas don't contain any data sources information I think so. The schemas have tables, views, triggers, ...  You can find data sources  inside a context file or somewhere else.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. And what exactly do you mean with "datasource"? JNDI DataSource? ODBC datasource?

Comment: I am using Exasol

Comment: In sql BD domain "datasource" generally refers to a client side property of the client's connection to a DB. Is it what you are after?

Comment: @Serg I think so. I'm not too familiar with Exasol or SQL itself, this was more of a learning task to try and figure it out, but it is turning out to be quite difficult.

Comment: Looks like Sql will not help.

Comment: @Serg ah thats unfortunate, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

If you have the auditing enable in your EXASOL database you can use the table `EXA_DBA_AUDIT_SQL` to find which SQL queries modified your table. The queries are in the `SQL_TEXT` column.

You can find more information about this table in the Appendix A of the EXASOL manual.